# Verificar se um usuário pertence a um grupo LDAP+PHP

Tags: php, openldap

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível verificar diretamente no AD, se um usuário pertence a um determinado grupo, para validá-lo como admin ou não.

Estou fazendo desta forma:

```
    /*
    * $this->status status da conexão
    * $this->ds identificador do link
    * $this->dn DN base
    * $this->usuario = usuário que busco no grupo
    */

    public function isAdmGroup() {

    if ($this->status) { 
        $grupo = 'CN=GrupoX,OU=Grupos,OU=Grupos de Acesso,DC=exemplo,DC=com,DC=br';
        $filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountname=".$this->usuario.")(memberOf=".$grupo."))";
        $attributes = array('memberof');
        $search = ldap_search($this->ds, $this->dn, $filter, $attributes);
        return ldap_get_entries($this->ds, $search);
    }
}
```

Porém, me retorna todos os grupos do usuário, e as vezes, é um array grande.

Eu gostaria de fazer uma pesquisa mais objetiva, apenas checando se é parte do grupo ou não, ao invés de retornar todos os grupos que o usuário pertence.

Comment: Verifique se isso ajuda. [LINK1](http://www.revistaphp.com.br/artigo.php?id=215)
[LINK2](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/471375-consultar-ad-usando-php/)
[LINK3](http://www.guj.com.br/java/111568-pegar-o-grupo-que-o-usuario-pertence-no-ldap)

Comment: Oi, obrigado, já havia dado uma olhada nestes links, mas queria algo mais específico.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode alterar a variável `$grupo` para o DN do grupo administradores que deseja e verificar se a função ldap_Search retorna algum objeto, se o retorno for vazio, indica que o usuário não é membro deste grupo.

Não há necessidade de verificar novamente o conteúdo do atributo memberOf a não ser que você queira processar os demais grupos que este administrador pode estar associado.